# How to keep two texts in the center of a canvas?

Tags: android, canvas

I'm new to work with Canvas in Android. I have the following code:

```
textGreetingsPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
textGreetingsPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
textGreetingsPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
textGreetingsPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

textSubGreetingsPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
textSubGreetingsPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
textSubGreetingsPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
textSubGreetingsPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);


final float startText = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
final float endText = ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((textGreetingsPaint.descent() + textGreetingsPaint.ascent()) / 2));
final float endSubText = endText + 150;

textGreetingsPaint.setTextSize(determineMaxTextSize("Good night,", (float) (getWidth() / 1.2)));
textSubGreetingsPaint.setTextSize(determineMaxTextSize("how was your day?", (float) (getWidth() / 1.2)));
canvas.drawText("Good night,", startText, endText, textGreetingsPaint);
canvas.drawText("how was your day?", startText, endSubText, textSubGreetingsPaint);


private int determineMaxTextSize(String str, float maxWidth) {
    int size = 0;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    do {
        paint.setTextSize(++size);
    } while (paint.measureText(str) < maxWidth);
    return size;
}
```

It basically insets two texts in the center of the canvas:

```
     Good night,
   how was your day?
```

I have the following issue - currently I set the `endSubText` to be `endText + 150`, meaning I will have the `Good night` message in the center of the screen and the `how was your day?` message under it, meaning I will have something like (note the empty rows):

```
>
>
>     Good night,
>
>   how was your day?
>
```

I want both of the messages to be in the center of the canvas, something like:

```
>
>     Good night,
>
>   how was your day?
>
```

Also, I set `endSubText` to be `endText + 150` with const `150` but it could be different in each screen. How to keep a valid margin between those two texts?

To sum up the questions:

1. How to set the texts in the center of the canvas?
2. How to keep valid margin between texts?

Comment: use Paint getTextBounds()